# Getting System Information when I click on a computer name in a document

Tags: powershell

I'd like to create a floor plan drawing of the office. in the drawing it will have the PC that's assigned to that particular cube. I'd like to make it so that when I click on the Computer name it will launch a fly out box that contains the system information for that particular PC.
In particular I'd like it contain
1. PC Name
2. OS Version
3. Bios Version
4. Install Date
5. Currently Logged in User

Just wondering if anyone has an idea on which way to go with this?

Comment: So you have just an idea and expect others to work it for you?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell isn't great for creating a GUI in. I've built a relatively simple one for a complex script and it's a pain to work in. There are tools you can use to help design it but there's a ton of background problems like `ListView.Sort()` doesn't work in an event and [piping anything in an invoke can crash the whole thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451759/piping-listview-items-in-separate-runspace). It's just not designed to work with forms.

That's not to say it's impossible. I would probably get an image of the floorplan, put it into a form and overlay it with buttons or links for each PC, tag them with the PC name and have it launch a script to retrieve and display the desired information. Depending on the number of PCs you would want to use something like PowerGUI or other designer, but you could also use C# or other more GUI-oriented languages and have them call PowerShell to get the information.